# Tkinter get status message from called function displayed in real time

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to show a status from a called function in real time. However, the messages appears in the GUI all at ones after function is done. What can I do?

Thanks for your help!

```
from tkinter import *

import time


def sleep():
    msgbox.insert(INSERT,"go sleep...\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    msgbox.insert(INSERT,"... need another 2 sec \n")
    time.sleep(2)   
    msgbox.insert(INSERT,"... that was good\n")
    return

root = Tk()
root.minsize(600,400)

button= Button(text="Get sleep", command=sleep)
button.place(x=250, y=100,height=50, width=100)

msgbox =Text(root, height=10, width=60)
msgbox.place(x=20, y=200)

mainloop()
```

Comment: You could learn about [`after()`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method).Sleep will block your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter: how to use after method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753719/7414759)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Tk.update()` function to update the window without having to wait for the function to finish:

```
from tkinter import *

import time


def sleep():
    msgbox.insert(INSERT,"go sleep...\n")
    root.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    msgbox.insert(INSERT,"... need another 2 sec \n")
    root.update()
    time.sleep(2)   
    msgbox.insert(INSERT,"... that was good\n")

root = Tk()
root.minsize(600,400)

button= Button(text="Get sleep", command=sleep)
button.place(x=250, y=100,height=50, width=100)

msgbox =Text(root, height=10, width=60)
msgbox.place(x=20, y=200)

mainloop()
```

(also the `return` is unnecessary, you use it if you want to end a function partway through or return a value from the function).

Let me know if you have any problems :).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees. Thanks a lot for your help!